# sqlite database showing error(no such table)

Tags: android

```
package com.pro;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;



public class SignUpActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText fname,lname,email,phnum,ad;

    Button save,reset;



    String s1_f,s2_l,s3_p,s4_a,s5_e;

    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    MainDataBase sud;

    SQLiteDatabase newDB;

    String tableName2 = MainDataBase.tableNamee12;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Fname);

        lname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);

        phnum=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phnnum);

        ad=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);

        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

        reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Reset);

        save.setOnClickListener(this);

        reset.setOnClickListener(this);

        s1_f=fname.getText().toString();

        s2_l=lname.getText().toString();


        s3_p=phnum.getText().toString();

        s4_a=ad.getText().toString();

        s5_e=email.getText().toString();

        sud=new MainDataBase(this.getApplicationContext());


    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(v==save){

            if(s1_f.equals(null)||s2_l.equals("")||

               s3_p.equals("")||s4_a.equals("")||

               s5_e.equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(this,"fill all the field",5000).show();
            }

            else{


            newDB = sud.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues obj_contenValues = new ContentValues();

            obj_contenValues.put(MainDataBase.col_firstName, s1_f);

            obj_contenValues.put(MainDataBase.col_password, s2_l);

            obj_contenValues.put(MainDataBase.col_phone, s3_p);

            obj_contenValues.put(MainDataBase.col_email, s5_e);


            obj_contenValues.put(MainDataBase.col_address, s4_a);

            newDB.insert(tableName2, null, obj_contenValues);

            newDB.close();

            newDB=sud.getReadableDatabase();

            String 
s=obj_contenValues.get(MainDataBase.col_firstName).toString();

            Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }   
            }


        if(v==reset){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SignUpActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }


        if(v==reset){

        //  fname.setText(null);

    }

}




    }01-23 17:20:53.446: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
01-23 17:21:06.397: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
01-23 17:21:08.657: E/BatteryService(72): usbOnlinePath not found
01-23 17:21:08.657: E/BatteryService(72): batteryVoltagePath not found
01-23 17:21:08.657: E/BatteryService(72): batteryTemperaturePath not found
01-23 17:21:08.696: E/SurfaceFlinger(72): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
01-23 17:22:01.427: E/EventHub(72): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
01-23 17:22:01.427: E/EventHub(72): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
01-23 17:22:02.377: E/System(72): Failure starting core service
01-23 17:22:02.377: E/System(72): java.lang.SecurityException
01-23 17:22:02.377: E/System(72):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
01-23 17:22:02.377: E/System(72):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
01-23 17:22:02.377: E/System(72):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
01-23 17:22:02.377: E/System(72):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
01-23 17:22:05.346: E/SoundPool(72): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-23 17:22:05.377: E/SoundPool(72): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-23 17:22:05.396: E/SoundPool(72): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-23 17:22:05.420: E/SoundPool(72): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-23 17:22:05.420: E/SoundPool(72): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-23 17:22:15.106: E/ThrottleService(72): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
01-23 17:22:15.146: E/ThrottleService(72): Error reading data file
01-23 17:22:16.336: E/logwrapper(153): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-23 17:22:16.407: E/logwrapper(158): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-23 17:22:16.466: E/logwrapper(159): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-23 17:22:24.636: E/logwrapper(166): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-23 17:22:24.706: E/logwrapper(167): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-23 17:22:24.796: E/logwrapper(168): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
01-23 22:52:52.696: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(72): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
01-23 22:52:52.996: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(72): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
01-23 22:52:53.166: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(72): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
01-23 22:52:53.477: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(72): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
01-23 22:53:24.077: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(33): failed to extract an album art
01-23 22:53:44.807: E/ThrottleService(72): Error reading data file
```

just check why my table is not created

Comment: Please try to narrow your problem down to specifically the code that is causing it. Simply posting all of your code and asking "what's wrong?" won't get you anywhere. (in life, or on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if you are debugging not on Emulator, but on the real device and that device has some real problems. The error messages are of system character.

Or(maybe and) your debugger had catched the info not from your application.

Try debugging on emulator first - it is easier.